# Share ctype memory across python processes using the address

Tags: python, ctypes, shared-memory

I am trying to send a dynamic array across multiple processes in python. My first solution was sending the data directly through the Queue/Pipe of multiprocessing class. The problem is that it is limited by the bandwidth of the ethernet connection. Therefore I am trying to use the ctype array and pass just the address of the object. When I try to access the array from the second process (either A.raw or A.value) the process exit without any exception. Does somebody have an idea what is going on? Maybe some problems with lock etc.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
from ctypes import c_char,addressof

from time import sleep
import os




class ProcessIn(Process):
    def __init__(self,QueueI):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.QueueI=QueueI

    def run(self):
        Array=[]
        while True:
            N=100000
            A=(c_char*N)()
            A.value=b'\x01'
            Address=addressof(A)
            Array.append(A)
            print(os.getpid(),'putted',Address)
            self.QueueI.put((Address,N))
            sleep(2)





class ProcessOut(Process):
    def __init__(self,QueueI):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.QueueI=QueueI

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(os.getpid(),'step 1')
            Address,N=self.QueueI.get()
            print(os.getpid(),'step 2',Address)
            A=(c_char*N).from_address(Address)      
            print(os.getpid(),'step 3')
            Value=A.raw         #This will fail 
            print(os.getpid(),'step 4',Value)   
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QueueI=Queue()

    In=ProcessIn(QueueI)
    Out=ProcessOut(QueueI)
    print(os.getpid(),'main')
    In.start()
    Out.start()
    input('press key to finish\n')
```

Comment: Have you read about shared memory in the multiprocessing module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the Array has static size, I would like to use a dynamic array

Comment: ctype Arrays are always fixed size, you have a python list called `Array` and add `c_char ` to it

Comment: Sure, but the idea is that the required array is created by the first process (with needed variable size), and then pass to the second process by its address and size. If I am correct the standard approach of multiprocessing Value and Array assume that the object is created in the main process and then passed to subprocesses - there is therefore not an option to change its size

Comment: [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html#arrays) may be of interest to you

Comment: You have shared memory but your `multiprocessing.Pipe` uses *Ethernet*?

Comment: It uses the sockets (internal IPC) - with limitation about 200MB/s. I am trying to process the external stream from through ethernet connection. Since that is already on the limit 100MB/s any additional use of local IPC through socket will slow it down.

Comment: I found out that the problem is that OS does not allow to access another process memory (I am using Win 10). The access violation is causing the crash. Does anybody know how to properly open the processes and set some access handles to be able to share the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it - using mmap with tag:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
from ctypes import c_char,addressof
import pyarrow as pa
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import os
import datetime
import mmap
from sys import getsizeof



class ProcessIn(Process):
    def __init__(self,QueueI):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.QueueI=QueueI

    def run(self):  
        i=0
        while True:
            N=np.random.randint(10,14)*100000
            data = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'        
            Tag='Data_'+str(i)
            buf = mmap.mmap(-1, N*len(data),tagname=Tag)            
            buf[0]=i
            NN=N*len(data)
            # print(buf[0:10])

            print(os.getpid(),'putted',Tag,NN)
            if self.QueueI.qsize()==0:
                self.QueueI.put((Tag,NN,datetime.datetime.now()))           


            i+=1
            sleep(1)


class ProcessOut(Process):
    def __init__(self,QueueI):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.QueueI=QueueI

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # print(os.getpid(),'step 1')
            Tag,N,start=self.QueueI.get()           
            buf =  mmap.mmap(-1, N,tagname=Tag)

            print('got',buf[0:10],Tag)

            # data=buf.read()
            dt=(datetime.datetime.now()-start).total_seconds()
            if dt!=0:
                print(os.getpid(),N/dt/1024**2,'MBs',dt*1000,'ms',N/1024**2,'MB',N) 
            else:
                print(os.getpid(),np.nan,'MBs',dt*1000,'ms',N/1024**2,'MB',N)   
            buf=None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QueueI=Queue()

    In=ProcessIn(QueueI)
    Out=ProcessOut(QueueI)
    print(os.getpid(),'main')
    In.start()
    Out.start()
    input('press key to finish\n')
```